# Is it possible to have two way composition in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, composition

First off I am very sorry if this is the wrong way to ask this question so please don't rip me. What I am trying to do is something very similar to the following.

```
class Driver:
    def __init__(self):
        self.kind = "Driver"
    def class_of_driver(self):
        if self.model == 'corvette':
            print('fast')
class Car:
    def __init__(self, brand, model, cost, color):
        self.brand = brand
        self.model = model
        self.cost = cost
        self.color = color
        self.drivers = Driver()
```

I want to be able to create the object like this:

```
corvette = Car('chevy','corvette','200','red')
```

Then ulitmately be able to do something like:

```
corvette.class_of_driver
```

or

```
corvette.class_of_driver()
```

and get the return of **fast** in this scenario. I have been messing with this for an hour and so and becoming stuck. I know I can pass self into itself like:

```
self.drivers = Driver(self)
```

But of course if the object changes in the future it will not reflect this change.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated and let me say thank you in advance.

Comment: "But of course if the object changes in the future it will not reflect this change." what do you mean, exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can. It is fairly common for two objects to hold references to each other. Here is one way to do it:

```
class Driver:
    def __init__(self, car):
        self.kind = "Driver"
        self.car = car
    def class_of_driver(self):
        if self.car.model == 'corvette':
            print('fast')
class Car:
    def __init__(self, brand, model, cost, color):
        self.brand = brand
        self.model = model
        self.cost = cost
        self.color = color
        self.driver = Driver(self)

    def class_of_driver(self):
        return self.driver.class_of_driver()


corvette = Car('chevy','corvette','200','red')

corvette.class_of_driver()
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly. I knew I was just overlooking something. Makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 3):

One easy way to do this would be to give the `Driver` a `Car` attribute by passing the Driver object to it on instantiation:

```
class Driver(object):
    def __init__(self, car):
        self.kind = "Driver"
        self.car = car
    def class_of_driver(self):
        if self.car.model == 'corvette':
            print('fast')
class Car(object):
    def __init__(self, brand, model, cost, color):
        self.brand = brand
        self.model = model
        self.cost = cost
        self.color = color
        self.drivers = Driver(self)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is very similar to the answer 1 minute ahead of you. This is a perfect answer though.